# How to output different audio channels to two different output devices

Tags: linux, windows, macos, sound-card, surround-sound

So I have a bit of a dilemma. I recorded a four channel audio file with a zoom h6 and I want to output the four channels to four different speakers. I have two stereo amplifiers set up and two soundcards but I need to know if there's a program for that can simultaneously output the channels to the different sound cards. The solution could be for Windows Mac or Linux because I own computer running all three. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Possibly https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for but still a good application

Comment: Is this for one-off home use, or are you looking for it to be portable; ie as a 5.1 soundtrack?

Comment: @Tetsujin Home use would work

Comment: You might be able to do it on Mac with [Loopback](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) or Win with [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) - I haven't actually tested either of those for that specific functionality, though.

Comment: Those are like the virtual audio cables in the other answer but the problem with that is that I need it to play different things on the two different sound cards

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @music2myear windows Mac or Linux, I will make it work.

Comment: Please use the EDIT button to add this information to your question.

Comment: @music2myear i mean in the question I did say that but I'll make it more clear

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index11h3

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in build 1803 of Windows 10, you can specify specific outputs per audio channel. No third-party software required.

In Settings > Sound > App Volume and Device Preferences, you are presented a selection of all currently active audio channels on the device and the ability to select the desired output of each of these:

[image]

*Image courtesy of GroovyPost.com: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/new-sound-settings-windows-10-1803-april-update/*

Comment: This would work, however I need the four audio channels to play at the respective files at the same time because the channels were all recorded simultaneously and therefore playback must be simultaneous as well. Using this solution I would have to have the files open in two different applications and the files wouldn't be played together